# iOS Image Localization

Tags: ios, localization

I noticed that when I localize an image I have to delete the app from my iDevice (simulator or real) or else the localized image won't show up (it shows the old unlocalized image). I'm updating my app with Portuguese localization, and I'm afraid the new images won't show up unless the players re-install the app, which is unacceptable.

Will it happen? Or the app update process is smarter than the Xcode simulator?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When u localize an image, u can press Cmd+Shift+k to clean build again, instead of deleting the app in simulator. App update process is definitely smarter. It will download the new changes and will doesn't require the user to reinstall..

Answer (score 1):

Yes the app update process is smarted than the simulator. 
Try to clean and build your project, think that should work for you.